# How to create a GWT Library jar from existing GWT Project?

Tags: gwt

I have a working GWT project library which I include to other GWT projects that need to use it. So far its been useful enough, however I need to make it a library jar, what is the process of doing it?

I tried to export the jar using File->Export->JAR File process with Eclipse however when I included the jar file in the same projects where I used to include the project file, it won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please be more specific about 1) what the "export to jar process" you tried was and 2) what you mean when you say "it won't work" - are there specific errors or failures you are seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you package *.java along with *.class. Module gwt.xml should also be placed in correct package.

See an example [here](http://roberthanson.blogspot.com/2006/05/how-to-package-gwt-components.html).

In eclipse export wizard, make sure "Export Java Source files and resources" checkbox is checked.

Comment: what do you mean by correct package, the GWT Library project I have works by just including it in other GWT application project? Do I need to modify anything, isn't it placed in the correct package already?

Comment: See the example I linked in my answer, in it `Components.gwt.xml` is placed in `org.hanson.gwt` package to be referenced like this: `<inherits name="'org.hanson.gwt.Components'/">`. So in the final jar `Components.gwt.xml` should be packaged in `org/hanson/gwt/` folder